# How to handle prepared statements/prevent SQL injection in Laravel 3 raw queries?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-3

Is there any best practice on how to prepare raw queries in order prevent SQL injection? My code looks like this (simplified for example - actual query is more complex or I would just use Fluent API):

```
$start = Input::get('start');
$end = Input::get('end');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `readings` ';
$query .= "WHERE `date` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."' ";

$readings = DB::Connection('customer')->first($query);
```

How should I do this to avoid the SQL injection risk above?

(note - above code is for Laravel 3 but the equivalent concept applies also in Laravel 4).

Comment: @chetan my question was how...

Answer (score 0):

use prepared statements to prevent sql injection

for Laravel , use  query builder http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries

```
$readings = DB::table('readings')
                    ->whereBetween('date', array($start, $end))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was about Laravel 3.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent SQL injection you should use parameters with domains(data types) instead of using string as parameters.Probably the easiest way will be to use ORM's or store procedures.
Why?
Because when you are using plain string as parameters,client can enter any value in parameter and attack you with sql injection !